# Dynamically grated grid with two nested flexbox not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a grid with a nested flexbox div. My code with two `for` loops does not work.

Whenever I try to do it without a string variable to assign id it can work, but if I use a variable to assign the id attribute it doesn't. Can you help me to find out what I may be doing wrong?

```js
$('#gameareaGrid').append('<div class="gridContainer" id="gridId">' + '</div>');

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let rowId = "row" + i;
  $('#gridId').append('<div class="rowContainer" id="+rowId+">' + '</div>');

  for (j = 0; j < nb_cols; j++) {
    $('"#"+rowId').append('<div class="cell" id=rowId+j>' + '</div>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to organise the single/double quotes correctly so as not to break the delimiting of the string when you concatenate values:

```js
$('#gameareaGrid').append('<div class="gridContainer" id="gridId"></div>');

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let rowId = "row" + i;
  $('#gridId').append('<div class="rowContainer" id="' + rowId + '"></div>');

  for (j = 0; j < nb_cols; j++) {
    $('#' + rowId).append('<div class="cell" id="' + (rowId + j) + '"></div>');
  }
}
```

I'd suggest using an editor with syntax highlighting as it makes it much easier to manage this.

Also note that dynamically generating elements with unique/incremental `id` attributes is an anti-pattern. I'd suggest using common classes and then relating the content by DOM traversal when an event occurs that you need to handle.

Comment: row.append('<div class="gridContainer" id="gridId">'+'</div>');
 row=$('#gridId');
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
  row.append('<div class="rowContainer" >'+'</div>');
  for(j=0;j<10;j++)
  {
   row.children()[i].append('<div class="cell" id=0+"_"+j></div>');
  }
 }

Comment: i have been trying to implement your sugestion and my div appended become normal string instead of html. What am I doing wrong?